# Size of a 3-level page table

Tags: memory, paging, page-tables

We have question:

> Calculate the maximum and minimum sizes of a single 3-level page table
>   for a 32-bit machine with a 4kB page size. The partitioning of the 20
>   bits representing a virtual page in this 3-level pge table is: (7, 7,
>   whatever bits remain).

I understand that minimum size should be 4k+4k+4k=12k because a process needs to have at least one frame allocated for itself. However I'm confused as to how to calculate the maximum. It works nicely with 2-level page tables because we can slice the 20 bits into 10 and 10 which works out nicely to 1024 entries * 4 bytes each which is a nice factor of 4k. But with 2^7 entires we get a strange number, any ideas on how to solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your question does not have an answer. This type of question is typical of the horrible operating systems textbooks out there.

First of all, you have no indication of the page table entry. Is is 32bits? 64bits? Are the entries the same size at each level of the page table?

It's not really possible for a process to have a 0-byte page table. There would need to be a least one page mapped for the process to executive. A minimum would then be 3 page table entries of whatever unspecified size (probably something like 12-bytes).

At to the maximum, that depends upon how the hardware and OS divides up the address space.

Comment: Unfortunately enough, the question doesn't specify. That is literally all the details the question provides. I would imagine that given a 32-bit machine that our entry is 32 bits. Other than that, anything else would have to be implied.

Comment: Where did the question come from?